# Invalid binding for Oracle UDT in procedure parameter

Tags: c#, odp.net, oracle-xe, user-defined-types

I'm attempting to call a procedure that takes a custom data type of `table of numbers` as one of the parameters.

Here is the definition of the type:

```
create type num_list as table of number;
```

And the definition of the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure
    (listofnumbers num_list,
                  v_value char)
is
begin

  update my_table
     set my_column = v_value
   where my_row_id in (select column_value
                         from table(listofnumbers));

end;
```

Using ODP.NET and C#, I'm declaring it as follows:

```
var row_ids = new int[] { 1, 2 };

using (var oracleConn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    oracleConn.Open();
    var cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("my_procedure", oracleConn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var param1 = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("listofnumbers", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Array, ParameterDirection.Input);
    param1.CollectionType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    param1.UdtTypeName = "num_list";
    param1.Value = row_ids;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

    var param2 = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("v_value ", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Char, ParameterDirection.Input);
    param2.Value = "Y";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The exception being thrown states:

> Invalid parameter binding Parameter
>   name: listofnumbers

What properties am I missing in defining the parameter?

Comment: Hi, how did you end upon up solving this? The answer below did not work for me.

Comment: Try the solution offered in the link I posted in my edited answer.

Comment: PS the answer below does work for me - you must not set the UdtTypeName but instead use the CollectionType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: May 14**

As my answer got unaccepted, here is a link that might be of use:

http://developergeeks.com/article/35/working-with-user-defined-type-oracle-udt-and-custom-type-using-odp-net-11g

---

Unfortunately I cannot play around with this as I have x64 ODP.NET which does not support UDT.

However, as your UDT is a collection did you try setting the Size property on param1?

```
param1.Size = row_ids.Length;
```

Now, it is not a UDT, but here is a code snippet how I bind to a type defined in a package spec as:

```
TYPE t_stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

```
            string[] values = new string[] { "AAA", "BBB" };

            OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
            parameter.Name = "my_param";
            parameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            parameter.ArrayBindSize = new int[values.Length];
            parameter.ArrayBindStatus = new OracleParameterStatus[values.Length];
            parameter.Size = values.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
            {
                parameter.ArrayBindSize[i] = 4000;
                parameter.ArrayBindStatus[i] = OracleParameterStatus.Success;
            }

            parameter.Value = values;
```

I am not sure what values you might set ArrayBindSize to.

Also, you might consider creating a type factory for your UDT:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featUDTs.htm

Anyway, I hope you find something here that helps.