# .NET Oracle UDT Parameter Binding (schema defined nested table)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, odp.net

In c#, I am trying to call a stored procedure that takes as input an instance of a defined type.

Schema defined type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE TEST.TBL_IDS IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64)
```

Stored procedure definition:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_PACKAGE.TEST_PROC(inIDs IN TEST.TBL_IDS);
```

My code in c# is as follows:

Class to map the Oracle data type + the required factory

```
public class TBL_IDS : INullable, IOracleCustomType
    {
        [OracleArrayMapping()]
        public string[] IDs;

        private bool objectIsNull;

        #region INullable Members

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return objectIsNull; }
        }

        public static TBL_IDS Null
        {
            get
            {
                TBL_IDS obj = new TBL_IDS();
                obj.objectIsNull = true;
                return obj;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        //must implement these for IOracleCustomType interface
        #region IOracleCustomType Members

        public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, 0, IDs);
        }

        //
        public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            IDs = (string[])OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, 0);
        }

        #endregion
    }

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("TEST.TBL_IDS")]
public class IDsFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory
{
    #region IOracleCustomTypeFactory Members
    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new TBL_IDS();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IOracleArrayTypeFactory Members
    public Array CreateArray(int numElems)
    {
        return new TBL_IDS[numElems];
    }

    public Array CreateStatusArray(int numElems)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The actual binding of the parameter:

```
string[] ids = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };
TBL_IDS tblIDs = new TBL_IDS();

OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "inIDs";
parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.UdtTypeName = "TEST.TBL_IDS";
parameter.Value = tblIDs;
```

The code compiles and runs successfully, but is not actually sending the array to the stored procedure. I've looked at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271605/invalid-binding-for-oracle-udt-in-procedure-parameter#) but the answer given does not work (which appears to be the case for other people who commented as well).

Comment: I notice you are coding the TBL_IDS class manually, which is fine. However, I thought I would point out for others that there is a code generation wizard as part of the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio that will help set up the required class automatically. Here is a tutorial: https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:116171970518298:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:10199,24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work now. The problem was due to the fact that my code treated the nested table as a table of custom defined types rather than a table of `varchar2(64)`.

Simply needed to change the mapping to the following (note that I removed `class TBL_IDS` since it isn't needed):

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("TEST.TBL_IDS")]
    public class TBL_IDS_FACTORY : IOracleArrayTypeFactory
    {
        #region IOracleArrayTypeFactory Members
        public Array CreateArray(int numElems)
        {
            return new string[numElems];
        }

        public Array CreateStatusArray(int numElems)
        {
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Actual binding in c# (just bind the string array instead of custom object):

```
string[] ids = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };
OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "inIDs";
parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.UdtTypeName = "TEST.TBL_IDS";
parameter.Value = ids ;
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem I had.

Comment: And since you are not using UDTs, the line "parameter.UdtTypeName" is also not needed.

Comment: Mark, in your case was TEST the schema so your UDT was globally scoped within the schema? Just to confirm. I have a package scoped one, and dont think those work rather well in a similar scenario :D I know it's been 5 years since you got your solution :D